# How to clean up a level traversal function?

Tags: haskell, tree, traversal

I am dealing with a general tree setup that is defined as follows:

```
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a] deriving (Eq, Read, Show)
```

With this setup, I have created a function that prints the nodes at a specific level of the tree (root is level 0, immediate children of root are level 1, etc.). This is the function:

```
level :: Int -> Tree a -> [a]
level 0 (Node a _) = [a]
level n (Node _ subtrees) = concatMap (level (n - 1)) subtrees
```

Using this function as a base, I created a second function, levelorder, which prints a list of all nodes in a tree in level order traversal. That function currently looks like this:

```
levelorder :: Tree a -> [a]
levelorder tree = level 0 tree ++ level 1 tree ++ level 2 tree ++ level 3 tree
```

While this works great for the tree I am currently working with, I would like to clean it up to where it would work with a tree of any size. As you can see, it currently only works on a tree with 4 levels (0 to 3). How would I go about achieving this to where I can still utilize the level function as a base?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had a function `depth :: Tree a -> Int` that told you how deep the tree was, it would be as simple as

```
levelorder tree = concatMap (\lvl -> level lvl tree) [0..depth tree]
```

This is not a particularly fast implementation, though, you end up traversing the tree many times.

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse the levels succesively until you run out of nodes:

```
levelorder :: Tree a -> [a]
levelorder t = concat $ takeWhile (not . null) $ map (`level` t) [0..]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a depth function first, so that you don't need to fix the number of levels you concatenate.

```
depth :: Tree a -> Int
depth (Node _ [])       = 1
depth (Node _ r@(x:xs)) = 1 + maximum (map depth r)
```

Then instead of fixing the number of times you use the `(++)` ,
you simply `concat` the results of `map`ing the level function over each level which you draw from a list `[0..depth tree]`.

`levelorder' tree = concatMap (flip level tree) [0..depth tree]`